# displaying html report of session user id

Tags: php, mysql

In my admin section, I want the user to be able to click a button and a HTML report to display all fields from all tables with the user id that is set in that session. 
So `$user_id = intval($_SESSION['user_id']);`

Would the button be something like:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['doReport'])) {

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");

$query = ("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = '$user_id');
}
// redirect to report page
            header('Location: report.php?id=' . $user_id);
?>
 <p align="center">
                <input name="doReport" type="submit" id="doThesisReport" value="View Report">
```

Also, what would be the best way to lay it out in the report page as I have 7 tables.
I am looking for a quick easy fix
Thank you!

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good way to achieve this would be :

- Make a button witch redirects to a new page, say "report.php".
- Now create the following logic for redirect page:

  1. Fetch the USER-ID from session using the code you've used above.
  2. Make the database connection on this page.
  3. You forgot to use `mysql_select_db();` to select the database.
  4. Write the query like :

     ```
     $query = ("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
     // you left "
     ```
  5. Fire the query using `$result=mysql_query($query)`; Note that the result from database is saved into `$result`.
  6. You can use tables to display data as per you liking but quick way would be to use `print_r($result)`
  7. Close the connection using `mysql_close();`

Hopefully since the question is not clear, I've posted the basic logic.

EDITED : forgot to put query in code block.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake: `"` char missed at the end of `$query` declaration.

I don't understand your trouble. If you want to use `$_SESSION['user_id']`, you can use it at any page without passing it in url.

And please don't put several questions in one.